# Extract assets images from a games APK

Tags: android, decryption, encryption, unpacking, apk

I'm trying to remove some images from an android game, but when I try to view them in a hexadecimal viewer I see that they don't contain a PNG header, so I can't view them through the python PIL library. Could someone help me to identify the pattern composed by this encryption?

[image]

I'm venturing into the field of extracting data from hexadecimal files, forgive the lack of knowledge or obvious things in the question

Comment: Can you post the file or at least its starting bytes  somewhere  in some form that allows to use it without OCR?

Comment: Of course I put the bytes of the file in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ME9a9Ak5